# Multiple dynamic Auto-renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

I have the following business model and I'm not sure is it possible to manage it using IAP.

The user can create and share with others premium content. The rest of users may subscribe "the content" to get an exclusive access in a specific period of time. Price list might be the same per each specific groups of products.

Example:

```
User A1 creates premium content P1 (price 0.99$ per month sub)
User A2 creates premium content P2 (price 0.99$ per month sub)
User A2 creates premium content P3 (price 0.99$ per month sub)

User A3 subscribe (auto-renewable) to P1, P2, P3 (A3 is charged three times every month)
User A4 subscribe (auto-renewable) to P2 and P3 (A3 is charged twice every month)
```

The problem I met so far:

1) When the premium content is adding dynamically, each new product has to be added to iTunes List. It's not scalable what if there are 10000 different premium products?

2) What if I'd just define the list of all possible auto-renewable price tires, for example, 10 different tires - it's still not possible to charge user more than once for a content using the same product_id.

Generally, It could be handled by custom server solution supported by Paypal or Stripe. The problem is that selling digital good requires that the In-App Payment need to be used.

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding 10,000 different IAPs is not scalable. Each new IAP also needs to be approved by Apple so this doesn't work.
2. It would be possible to create multiple subscription products at different prices. If you put them in the same [subscription group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_store/auto-renewable_subscriptions/subscription_groups), you would be able to initiate a new IAP to migrate the user from tier to tier without a gap in billing. I would suggest selling a smaller number of tiers (0-5, 5-10, 10+) rather than forcing the user through an upsell experience every time they added a single new subscription.

Comment: referring to #2 it doesn't allow to subscribe more than once, looking at example with P1, P2 and P3 cannot be subscribed in the same time. Just after successful payment after P1, you cannot proceed payment for P2/P3 because is already subscribed.

Comment: @mbutan did you find any solution for this?